# is it possible DOMContentLoaded fired before DOMContentLoaded in this case

Tags: reactjs, dom

developing a carousel with react

have this line of code to detect whether html load or not. if load set auto play true, code works, carousel rotate as independent module however when import the carousel module to the page it carousel stop rotate since isAutoPlay always false. The page contains a lot of other modules.
check old stackoverlfow post said componentDidMount before DOMContentLoaded, how could this not work. Thanks any idea

```
componentDidMount() {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this._handleLoad);

  }

  _handleLoad() {
    this.setState({
      isAutoPlay: true
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call auido.play(), it's better than autoplay. And DOMContentLoaded  in my opinion only call once and componentdidmount can call many times. And maybe when your module loaded, html has already been loaded.